# Call PHP function from AMD module moodle

Tags: javascript, php, moodle, amd

For moodle development I want to load an AMD module:

```
$this->page->requires->js_call_amd('mod_newmodule/testamd', 'init', array($content));
```

`testamd.js` looks like this:

```
define(['jquery'], function ($) {
return {
    init : function(content) {
        $(".myclass").click(function () {
                alert("test");
            });
        }
};    
});
```

Instead of `alert()`, I want to do a database query on button click. How can I call a php function (which does the query) from my AMD module? Or should it be written inside AMD? But then again how? Is there something like a best practice?

Besides I don't get to where the `init` is returned.

```
$var = $this->page->require->...
```

Nothing returned to `$var`?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot query the database directly, since js is a client-sided script you will have to [develop a web-service](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Adding_a_web_service_to_a_plugin). Then you may call it via

`var promises = Ajax.call([{
                methodname: 'YOUR_WEBSERVICE_METHOD_NAME',
                args: {
                    exampleid: MYID,
                    examplestring: MYSTRING
                }
            }]);
            //resolve promise
            promises[0].then(function(data) {
                //data contains webservice answer
            }`